# asp.net localization decimal point

Tags: c#, asp.net, server

I have a problem where numbers i export from my server with decimal numbers are using the decimal sign instead of a point making it not appear on the screen as shown on the images

image of screen

[image: image of screen]

image of Elements

[image: image of Elements]

and here if i replace in manualy with a dot

image of screen

[image: image of screen]

i dont know whats happening since it should be imposible for a double to have a comma in it.

i have tried changing around the double to a string and that works but it only avoids the problem, and i dont want to be able to save text in price.

View code:

```
@model Produkt
@{
    <form asp-action="sparaProdukt" method="post">
        <div id="in">
            <h2>ID:</h2>
            <h1>@Model.id</h1>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@Model.id">
        <div id="in">
            <label for="Name">name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="produktnamn" name="produktnamn" value="@Model.produktnamn">
        </div>
        <div id="in">   
            <label for="Supplier">Supplier:</label>
            <input type="text" id="Supplier" name="tillverkare" value="@Model.tillverkare">
        </div>
        <div id="in">
        <label for="Info">Info:</label>
            <input type="Info" id="Info" name="produktinfo" value="@Model.produktinfo">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <label for="Price">Price:</label>
                <input type="number" id="Price" name="pris" class="Price" value="@Model.pris" step="0.01" min="0" lang="en">
                <span>| kr</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
    </form>
}
```

Model code:

```
using Webbshop.Models;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Webbshop.Models
{
    public class Produkt
    {
        public string produktnamn { get; set; } = "";
        public string produktinfo { get; set; } = "";
        public string tillverkare { get; set; } = "";
        public double pris { get; set; } = 0;
        public long id { get; set; } = 0;

        public static bool sparaProdukt(Produkt p)
        {

            string conStr = "server=|removed|;user=|removed|;port=|removed|;database=|removed|;password=|removed|";

            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conStr);
            MySqlCommand MyCom = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE Produkt set produktnamn = @PRNAMN, tillverkare = @TILL, pris = @PRIS where id = @ID ", conn);
            MyCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRNAMN", p.produktnamn);
            MyCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TILL", p.tillverkare);
            MyCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRIS", p.pris);
            MyCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", p.id);
            conn.Open();

            int rader = MyCom.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MyCom.Dispose();
            conn.Close();

            if (rader == 0) return false; else return true;


        }

    }
```

Controller code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Webbshop.Models;

namespace Webbshop.Controllers
{
    public class ProduktController : Controller
    {
        List<Produkt> allaP = new List<Produkt>();
        Produkt P = new Produkt();
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(Produkt.getAllProdukt());
        }
        public IActionResult newProdukt()
        {    
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult redigeraProdukt(int id)
        {
            Produkt p = Produkt.getSingleProduktById(id);
            
            return View(p);

        }
        public IActionResult sparaProdukt(Produkt p)
        {
            Produkt.sparaProdukt(p);
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you create that HTML element, as [edit] to your code?

Comment: added a picture that shows where the HTML element is created

Comment: Please post all possible information as text. Code will be nicely colorized. Screenshots could be abstracted to the relevant information (unless the actual layout/color/etc. is important). That makes it easier for others to read your question, copy code to try things out, etc. Other than that, what is the client locale (culture/language) of the computer where you view the page?

Comment: Post your code and data as *text*, not images. Images can't be compiled, tested or googled. Decimal numbers are binary values, they have no format. Formats apply when formatting the numbers as text for display or exporting. When that happens the application specifies the format through the CultureInfo, either directly or indirectly. In a web app the CultureInfo to use is affected by server settings, the code and the end user's `Accept-Language` settings.

Comment: swedish i believe

Comment: Then I believe what @PanagiotisKanavos said could be the reason for what you are seeing. In short: the browser sends the Accept-Language header with "Swedish" (se), the server will use that to create a CultureInfo that will then determine the "default" (current) culture for the request. Dates, numbers, etc. will then be formatted like that culture mandates by default (and Swedish uses a comma as decimal separator). I suggest you read up on ASP.NET Core and localization topics.

Comment: For specific input types, data binding is *not* affected if done right. For example for `type="date"` the value is always ISO8601 but the actual displayed format matches the culture specified in the HTML head. In the MDN [decimal numeric example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#allowing_decimal_values) you can't even enter the wrong separator